# Formal word/phrase meaning enable something for the first time

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to think of a word or phrase for a formal document that has the meaning: "enable something for the first time." I'm unable to find anything suitable, unfortunately.

Consider the sentence:

> The culmination of which is likely to be seen in 2020, as initial
>   business licenses _________ operations and expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the repetition with *initial*, I'd use **initiate**, which means to :

> The culmination of which is likely to be seen in 2020, as business licenses initiate operations and expansion.

[Merriam-Webster](http://:%20to%20cause%20or%20facilitate%20the%20beginning%20of%20:%20set%20going) gives this as a first definition for the verb:

> : to cause or facilitate the beginning of : set going

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the word **activate**.